# Repository query conditions, dependencies and DRY

Tags: php, domain-driven-design, dry, separation-of-concerns

To keep it simple, let's suppose an application which has `Accounts` and `Users`. Each account may have any number of users. There's also 3 consumers of `UserRepository`:

- An admin interface which may list all users
- Public front-end which may list all users
- An account authenticated API which should only list it's own users

Assuming `UserRepository` is something like this:

```php
class UsersRepository extends DatabaseAbstraction {
    private function query() {
        return $this->database()->select('users.*');
    }
    public function getAll() {
        return $this->query()->exec();
    }
    // IMPORTANT:
    // Tons of other methods for searching, filtering,
    // joining of other tables, ordering and such...
}
```

Keeping in mind the comment above, and the necessity to abstract user querying conditions, How should I handle querying of users filtering by `account_id`? I can picture three possible roads:

#### 1. Should I create an `AccountUsersRepository`?

```php
class AccountUsersRepository extends UserRepository {
    public function __construct(Account $account) {
        $this->account = $account;
    }
    private function query() {
        return parent::query()
            ->where('account_id', '=', $this->account->id);
    }
}
```

*This has the advantage of reducing the duplication of `UsersRepository` methods, but doesn't quite fit into anything I've read about DDD so far (I'm rookie by the way)*

#### 2. Should I put it as a method on `AccountsRepository`?

```php
class AccountsRepository extends DatabaseAbstraction {
    public function getAccountUsers(Account $account) {
        return $this->database()
            ->select('users.*')
            ->where('account_id', '=', $account->id)
            ->exec();
    }
}
```

*This requires the duplication of all `UserRepository` methods and may need another `UserQuery` layer, that implements those querying logic on chainable way.*

#### 3. Should I query `UserRepository` from within my account entity?

```php
class Account extends Entity {
    public function getUsers() {
        return UserRepository::findByAccountId($this->id);
    }
}
```

*This feels more like an aggregate root for me, but introduces dependency of `UserRepository` on `Account` entity, which may violate a few principles.*

#### 4. Or am I missing the point completely?

Maybe there's an even better solution?

**Footnotes:** Besides permissions being a Service concern, in my understanding, they shouldn't implement SQL query but leave that to repositories since those may not even be SQL driven.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep all `User` related data-access in the `UserRepository`. It is not a good idea to make repositories depend on each other but it's perfectly ok to have a service depend on multiple repositories. So in this case you could have an `AccountService` which uses both `UserRepository` and `AccountRepository`.

The third option you have considered is something I've also used and it has the benefit that now the user list is loaded lazily (although this can be accomplished by other means as well). The huge drawback is that it will be very hard to serialize that object to send it over wire for example and it also couples the data-access layer with your object model.

Comment: Hmmm, one of our problems is that there are a lot of conditional joins, complex query combinations and they are mostly based on user input. We are already trying to figure out how we can achieve that elegantly either by decoration or specification pattern. I suppose that wrapping it all with a Service may add even more complication.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few principles in play here that may affect your design:

**Aggregates** - if `Account` is your top level item (aggregate root) for this aggregate, that should be your repository. You don't necessarily need one repository per table, as that breaks any domain encapsulation that you're trying to achieve.  Based on this, I'd consider a single AccountRepository, which has options to pull Users by Account (ex: `findUsersInAccount(Account $account)` ) Your concern about joins here is what makes me suspect this is the case.

**Bounded Contexts** - Be careful not to stuff everything into a single bounded context. Often, admin and public interfaces are performing entirely different business goals, and they can be separated as such. Mind you, if both are trutly just findAll() calls, ignore this, but I doubt this is the case. I don't know your application, but perhaps the admin side acts on multiple Accounts, whereas the public side only acts on a single one (the user's account). Having two different subdomains (or bounded contexts) is often better than one perfect one that is skewed trying to fit each.

**Reality** - Now, assuming what you have still satisfies the above and you are running into problems, wrapping both in a service is probably the way to go. That service can hide all of the repository access (from multiple repositories).

However, in the effort of good OO design, and especially DDD, I'd advise against the following:

- Extending repositories from each other UNLESS it's abstract. Interfaces are often more appropriate here if you want to re-use patterns.
- Building your repositories around your SQL schema. Don't assume a SQL back-end, as that mapping will be evident in your domain model; exactly where it's not allowed to be.

Anyway, without understanding your domain fully, it seems something like this should satisfy your needs:

```
interface AccountRepository
{
    function findUsersInAccount(Account $account);
}

interface UserRepository
{
    function findAll()
}
```

Your domain model can expose multiple interfaces for its *needs*, while your actual database implementations of those repositories can be mashed together if needed. Just focus on what your domain needs, and worry about how it's implemented later.

Finally, DDD is meant for applications with complex domains. Applying it where it's not needed can lead to a lot of confusion because many of the benefits don't necessarily apply.

Comment: A lot have evolved in my mind since I've first asked this and I agree with almost everything you say. But I still have one question: Isn't it better to have a `findByAccountId(id)` method on `UserRepository` or even a `match(UserCriteria criteria)` and let controllers handle permissions?

Comment: Depends - are permissions a domain-specific constraint, or are they generic application-level permissions? (Really, it depends how far you want to apply DDD, because there is no right answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, I would suggest you to model both Account and User as aggregate roots (with own their repositories). So, if you need all account's users you could do it this way:

```
interface UserRepository
{
    public function findAll();
    public function findByAccount(Account $account);
}
```

You are free to "recycle" your code inside infrastructure layer (implementation side), you could do it this way:

```
class UserRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepository implements UserRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->query('user');
    }

    public function findByAccount(Account $account)
    {
        // ...
    }
}

class AccountRepositoryImpl extends BaseRepository implements AccountRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->query('account');
    }
}

abstract class BaseRepository
{
    protected function query($type = 'user')
    {
        // common part 1
        if ($type == 'account')
            $q .= 'AND account_id = ...';
        // common part 2
    }
}
```

Just remember one thing, model (including repository interface) shouldn't deal with concerns like this. It's always a bad idea to change your model according to DB access needs.